# MVC5 Add/Append Headers to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to add a refresh/redirect header to my pages.

In asp.net web-forms I do this

```
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='{0};url={1}'>",  "1", "http://www.google.co.uk")));
```

and I can see this `<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='7200;url=http://www.google.co.uk'>` in the page source and all is good.

I've just switched to **MVC5/VS2015/C#** and have tried to do the same using a global filter. This does everything else that I need the filter to do but it doesn't seem to want add the header. I have placed this in `OnActionExecuting` and in `OnActionExecuted`

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("refresh", string.Format("content='{0};url={1}'", "1", "http://www.google.co.uk"));
```

I have created filters, and applied them to the controller, action methods, global filters, pretty much anywhere I can find.

In desperation, in the page and the layout pages (pretty much everywhere I could think) of using Razor I have tried (below)

```
Response.AppendHeader("refresh", string.Format("content='{0};url={1}'", "1", "http://www.google.co.uk"));
Response.AddHeader("refresh", string.Format("content='{0};url={1}'", "1", "http://www.google.co.uk"));
```

Every article I've looked at (and I've looked at loads) suggests I am doing it correctly. I get no errors but it just doesn't seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated.